# Set default option in php dropdown and retain when submitted query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have below code which creates drop-down from php. I want to achieve 2 things here. 
1. I want to set one of the option to be set default. It may be hard coded or selected from query.
2. When hit button, it should retain selected option. I could retrieve selected option using session data with this: `echo $print_version1[array_keys($print_version1)[0]];`

**Drop-down code:**

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT DISTINCT nx_version FROM workflow1 ORDER BY id DESC");
echo "<form action='http://localhost/w_5aug/process.php' method='get'>";
echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<p></p>";
echo "<center>";
echo "<strong> Select Base Verison To Compare With : </strong>";
echo "<select name='nx_version' id='nx_version'>";
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
             $nx_version = $row['nx_version']; 
             echo '<option>'.$nx_version.'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
echo "&nbsp;<button type='submit'><b>Add Base Verison</b></button>";    
echo "</center>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
echo "<p></p>"; 

$array_select = $_SESSION['data'];
print_r($array_select);
echo "<form>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume that the option that should be selected  is$print_version1[array_keys($print_version1)[0]

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $nx_version = $row['nx_version']; 

         if($_SESSION["id"])  {
           if($nx_version == "the hardcode value you want to be selected"){
              echo '<option selected="selected">'.$nx_version.'</option>';
           }else{
              echo '<option>'.$nx_version.'</option>';
           }
         }else{
           if($print_version1[array_keys($print_version1)[0]] == $nx_version){
             echo '<option selected="selected">'.$nx_version.'</option>';
           }else{
             echo '<option>'.$nx_version.'</option>';
           }
        }

 }
```

Comment: Getting error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)`

Comment: Still it shows some default value, but `echo $print_version1[array_keys($print_version1)[0]];` returns correct version.

Comment: can you please tell what  $nx_version and $print_version1[array_keys($print_version1)[0]] returns

Comment: Oh, it's working after adding session code like `$array_id = $_SESSION['id'];` before above form code. 90% issue resolved. Now how can I set one of the nx_version as default which will be either selected from query or hard coded?

Comment: you mean when you load it for the first time or if your session is empty ther should be a default option selected

Comment: Yeah, right now from 5 distinct values, I think, last one is default one, but I may need to set default to 2nd or 3rd one or I will hard code default option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152378/discussion-between-anil-shrestha-and-samadhan-gaikwad).

Comment: @ Anil Shrestha, can you help me in this, [Run query on page load](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1202938/Run-query-with-default-option-from-PHP-select-quer)